# How to resolve incompatible version of kotlin in gradle file in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, gradle-kotlin-dsl

META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried with kotlin version 1.7.10 and 1.9.22(latest) but this error still come.
how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u recently updated ur android studio. change ur kotlin version.

```
location--> android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

location--> android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip
```

2. in flutter terminal -> flutter clean
3. in flutter terminal -> flutter pub get
4. delete ur (android/.gradle) fille  [remember .gradle. don't delete gradle file]
5. run ur project again.